# Strike only first one MAX cell value on row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, conditional-formatting, strikethrough

Just need help with this problem. I used this for conditional formatting:
=F5:J5=MAX($F5:$J30). I have 5 columns with values which I need to filter.

It's okey but when I have the same value I need to strike only one of them not all of them.

Comment: Change to this `=F5=MAX($F$5:$J$30).`

Comment: This can be done, but need to see some example data to put in the conditional formatting formula with a countif

Comment: @ScottCraner wont that still cross out every case that is true as its copied across?

Comment: Nope because the F5 is relative it will change with the range of the cells in the Applies To: so only the one that is equal will return true.

Comment: @ScottCraner What if J5 and F5 are equal and are both the max?

Comment: You are correct it will every one. @ForwardEd I missed where he did not want duplicates.  I thought he was worried about the full row being struck through.

Comment: @ScottCraner  I WAS reading your answer and you shed a whole new understanding on the question I was reading.  You were basically striking out just the cells that were equal to the maximum.

Comment: @ScottCraner I was thinking of doing something like `countif($F$5:F5,MAX($F5:$J30))>1  but without seeing the data layout I was not sure about where to put the $ locks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this formula:

```
=F5=MAX($F$5:$J$30)
```

That way it will only compare one cell at a time.

[image]

If what you want is the first max only then use this formula:

```
=AND(F5=MAX($F$5:$J$30),COUNTIF($F5:F5,F5)=1,COUNTIF($F$4:$J4,F5)=0)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: 3rd option, strike out everyone after the first one! 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd `=AND(F5=MAX($F$5:$J$30),COUNTIF($F$5:F5,F5)>1)`

Comment: I think we have the bases covered!

Comment: Now the question I have in the back of my mind, why use the AND with two conditionals instead of putting the MAX portion right in the COUNTIF? never mind I think I just figured it out

Comment: @ForwardEd because of the method by which excel iterates, I needed to add a third criterion.  See edit.

Comment: wow, I had not considered that a 3rd criteria would be needed.  boggles my mind.  I was thinking that if you shoved the max into the countif and skipped the and statement, you would I wind up striking out EVERYTHING after the occurrence of the second maximum.

Comment: Yes you would strike through a lot more than just the one. @ForwardEd